# Setting values in SWF, Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, flash, editing

I am trying to set values for a SWF file. I have the SWF in a web view, but I need to set values for it. How would I set values for it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by “set values for a SWF file”?

Answer (score 0):

I need to communicate with the SWF file and set values on it.

here: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=502922

Go to the "2 way communication setting SWF values" part.

Comment: similar to this: http://wiki.eltima.com/user-guides/flash-in-app-macos/communication-with-flash.html

Comment: You should edit this into your question instead of posting it as an answer.